# Is it sin to enjoy watching animals getting eaten by other animals?

Tags: halal-haram

Like in the title said is it sin to watch animals being eaten by their prey alive. I kinda find enjoyment and entertainment to watch it. I'm wondering if it's sin.

Comment: What makes you think it's a sin. "I kinda find enjoyment and entertainment to watch it" please go to an psychologist for the sake of your own mental health.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a sin to watch people commit sins, but Animals don't commit a sin when they eat another animal, at least the action of watching it is not a sin.

Some extremist people asked one of the companions (ra) if it was permissible to kill a fly, he became angry at them for asking, since they where killing some of the best people with no problem, yet they hesitated to kill a bug.

So don't worry too much about that, worry more about your relation to people around you.

Comment: since they where killing some of the best people with no problem. what do you mean.

Comment: They killed companions of the messenger, peace be upon him, once they robbed and killed a man and his pregnant wife, so how can you do that and then be worried about killing a bug. Human life is very valuable in Islam.

Comment: OK thanks for clarification